# G*Power-Repeated measures MANOVA "number of measurements" input field

Tags: repeated-measures, sample-size, statistical-power, manova

I am trying to calculate the sample size needed with G*Power for my dissertation study.  I will be doing a Repeated Measures MANOVA within/between interaction.  My question is in the field "number of measurements," is this simply the number of DVs (I will have 3) or do I mutiply that by the number of times I will be collecting data on the DVs (with 2 groups at 2 times which would be 12)?